# Copy Data from one Sqlite table to another Sqlite table

Tags: c#, sqlite, ado.net

I need to copy data from one Sqlite table to another.
I wrote method, which return DataTable:

```
public static DataTable GetDataFromSecondTable(string filePath)
    {
        DataTable DbTable = new DataTable("Messages");
        using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(filePath))
        {
            string SelectQuery = "SELECT * FROM Messages";
            using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(SelectQuery, connection))
            {
                connection.Open();         

                using (SQLiteDataAdapter adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    adapter.Fill(DbTable);                        
                }
            }
        }
        return DbTable;
    }
```

Then I need to insert this DataTable to my "main" table, which has same structure:

```
public static void MergeData(string mainDbPath, string secondDbPath)
    {
        DataTable secondTable = GetDataFromSecondTable(secondDbPath);

        using(SQLiteConnection connect = new SQLiteConnection(mainDbPath))
        {
            connect.Open();
            using (var cmd = new SQLiteCommand(connect))
            {
                using (var transaction = connect.BeginTransaction())
                { 
                    foreach(DataColumn column in secondTable.Columns)
                    {
                        foreach(DataRow row in secondTable.Rows)
                        {                                
                            //cmd.CommandText = String.Format("INSERT INTO Messages ('{0}') VALUES('{1}')", column.ColumnName, row);                              
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }

                    transaction.Commit();
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

I don't understand how I should set rows and columns to SQLite query. Maybe someone have another solution for this task.

Comment: You need to write out the complete INSERT statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A INSERT statement needs to be specific. I mean using '*' like you can do in a SELECT statement does not work for INSERT (or UDPATE for that matter).

You need to specify the columns one by one or insert the data in the exact same order the table was created.
So for example, let's say your `Messages` table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE Messages(
   ID INT PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL,
   POSTERNAME     TEXT    NOT NULL,
   MESSAGE        CHAR(500)     NOT NULL
);
```

When you insert data in this table you can use an INSERT statement like this:

```
INSERT INTO Messages (ID,POSTERNAME,MESSAGE) 
       VALUES (1,'SomeGuy','SomeMessage');
```

or use the short syntax:

```
INSERT INTO Messages VALUES (1,'SomeGuy','SomeMessage');
```

in your code you could use this like:

```
using (SQLiteConnection connect = new SQLiteConnection(mainDbPath))
{
    connect.Open();
    using (var transaction = connect.BeginTransaction())
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in secondTable.Rows)
        {
            var cmdText= string.Format("INSERT INTO Messages VALUES ({0},'{1}','{2}');",
                row["ID"], row["POSTERNAME"], row["MESSAGE"]);

            using (var cmd = new SQLiteCommand(cmdText, connect, transaction))
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }

        transaction.Commit();
    }
}
```

Notice that I changed the order of the usings. You probably want to commit the transaction only when **all** records have been succesfully added to the database. SO first start the transaction before you create the command.

You can do this a lot simplier by using a SELECT statement in the INSERT like this:

```
INSERT INTO SECONDTABLE SELECT COL1,COL2,COL3 FROM FIRSTTABLE
```

You offcourse need to replace with proper table and column names.

Answer (score 0):

```
SQLiteCommand createCommand = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();
createCommand.CommandText = $"CREATE TABLE `{CopyTable}` AS SELECT * FROM `{SourceTable}`";
```

Use this command, this will help you to make a copy of another table.
Copy table - new table name